# Broken dependencies when upgrading SLES 11.3 to 11.4

Tags: linux, upgrade, suse, sles

I'm trying to upgrade SLES 11.3 to 11.4 **with zypper** using the following instructions:
https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_deployment/data/sec_update_sle11sp3.html

After launching the following command:
**zypper dup --from SLE11-SDK-SP4-Pool**

I get the following problems:

```
3 Problems:
Problem: nothing provides yast2 >= 2.17.140 needed by yast2-dns-server-2.17.24-1.2.noarch
Problem: nothing provides yast2 >= 2.17.140 needed by yast2-ca-management-2.17.27-1.1.noarch
Problem: nothing provides product(SUSE_SLE) = 11.4 needed by sle-sdk-release-SDK-11.4-1.55.x86_64

Problem: nothing provides yast2 >= 2.17.140 needed by yast2-dns-server-2.17.24-1.2.noarch
 Solution 1: Following actions will be done:
  deinstallation of yast2-dns-server-2.17.23-0.5.1.noarch
  deinstallation of yast2-dhcp-server-2.17.6-0.4.2.21.noarch
 Solution 2: keep obsolete yast2-dns-server-2.17.23-0.5.1.noarch
 Solution 3: break yast2-dns-server-2.17.24-1.2.noarch by ignoring some of its dependencies
```

What should I do?

Comment: This is a question that may be better on the SuperUser site or Unix.stackexchange. It would also get a quick response on the openSuSE user mailing list (`opensuse@opensuse.org`) Looking at the error, it looks like you are missing a repository that holds the updated `yast2` packages.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try with the 2 other forums!